# Eclipse java project forName() classnotfoundexception

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to do a Java Project in Eclipse in Win7 and I wanted to test some methods. But when I `run as Java application` I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

And it also pointed this line:

```
Class.forName("ceng.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

I looked at some questions here with the same error code and it is like there is a different syntax for this code. But my teacher gave me this code and it was working in Ubuntu. Maybe this is caused because I use Windows.

I have 2 files in the same package, one of them is the Main.java. I put the mysql...jar thing on a folder named lib inside the project and put it also to the build path.

Anyway, how can I fix this? Thank you for advance :)

Comment: When you said added Jar to Build path. Have you added that to Eclipse builpath ? Eclipse is unable to find the jar which you set in the buildpath.

Comment: Firstly, thank you to reply. I right click the project on the package explorer, then I click to properties, then to java build path. After that I opened the libraries option and add jars. I choose the jar which I putted into the lib folder inside my project. Should I do something more?

Comment: is the jars you have added appearing in the referenced libraries

Comment: Yes, there is only 1 jar after all.

Comment: I didn't understand. There is only 1 jar I will use and it is in the referenced libraries already.

Comment: Yes Kalahari as @johny mentioned in the answers. Change the ceng to com and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
Class.forName("ceng.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

to

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

There is a package called `com.mysql.jdbc` in the jar you have added and inside that a class named `Driver` is there.

Comment: Firstly, thank you to reply. I use a package named "ceng.ceng351.cpl". I must use it. This is why it is "Class.forName("ceng.mysql.jdbc.Driver");"

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I was thinking that com thing should be the same with my package.